# Not able to Create AVD using command line

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-manager

I have downloaded the basic Android command line tools from [devloper.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), now i am creating a new AVD using following command

`avdmanager create avd --package 'platforms;android-26;google_apis;x86' -n test-1`

Its giving error

`Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:`

I have already installed the package using [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html) and its available in my sdk folder under platforms.

Answer (score 8):

First, you need to download the necessary packages. 
Here is an example of downloading API 23 packages for x86 emulators:

```
 ./sdkmanager "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86"
```

and then create your emulator:

```
./avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86" -b x86 -c 100M -d 7 -f
```

Or you can try with this sample steps:

```
android update sdk -u --filter platform-tools,android-25
sdkmanager --verbose "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86"
```

and then create the avd using:

```
avdmanager -v create avd -n x86 -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86" -g "google_apis"
```

Comment: Command `sdkmanager "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86"` executed succesfully with one warning as `File C:\Users\username\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded` after executing second command `./avdmanager create avd -n test -k "system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86" -b x86 -c 100M -d 7 -f
` getting error as : `Error: Invalid --tag default for the selected package.
`   
FYI : I am using windows 7.

Comment: Also please tell how will i know that selected package got installed.

Comment: @Meetesh, manually create the repositories.cfg file and try download the system image again using sdkmanager cmd. Then avdmanager cmd should work